# Frequency Distribution Comparison

Tags: python, algorithm, statistics, nlp, corpus

Long story short: I've got two corpus and want to compare the two word frequency distributions to find the biggest differences from the norm in Python.

EG: I've got forum talk using jargon, I'd like to identify the differences between this and a control/general corpus. The two corpus would be diferent sizes and I'd want to control against one corpus not featuring a term at all and making the relative difference overly large.

In my research I've come across the [TF-IDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf)  but it's not for comparison, could it be re-purposed to be used to compare?